# Converter código java para pascal

Tags: java, delphi, firemonkey

Preciso converter para Pascal / Firemonkey o código java abaixo:

as principais dúvidas são:

- como extrair cada pixel em firemonkey?
- como opera esse código: `slice |= (byte) ((v ? 1 : 0) << (7 -b));`

Segue o código completo:

```
public static boolean ImageToEsc(Bitmap im, OutputStream out, int bytes, Integer density)
        {           
            try 
            {           

                int wid = im.getWidth();
                int hei = im.getHeight();
                byte[] blen = new byte[2];

                int [] dots = new int[wid * hei];
                im.getPixels(dots, 0, wid, 0, 0, wid, hei);

                blen[0] = (byte) (wid / 8);
                blen[1] = (byte) bytes; 

                int offset = 0;
                while (offset < hei) 
                {               

                    for (int x = 0; x < wid; ++x) 
                    {
                        for (int k = 0; k < bytes; ++k) 
                        { 
                            byte slice = 0;

                            for (int b = 0; b < 8; ++b) 
                            {
                                int y = (((offset / 8) + k) * 8) + b;

                                int i = (y * wid) + x;

                                boolean v = false;
                                if (i < dots.length) {
                                    v = (dots[i]==Color.BLACK);
                                }

                                slice |= (byte) ((v ? 1 : 0) << (7 -b));
                            }

                            out.write(slice);
                        }
                    }                   
                    offset += (bytes * 8);                  
                }
```

Comment: Veja se ajuda http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firemonkey

Answer (score 2):

Vou responder apenas essa parte :

```
slice |= (byte) ((v ? 1 : 0) << (7 -b));
```

Cada parte :

```
|=
```

O operador pipe "|" no java significa operação OU, e quando associado ao "=" na forma curta implica em

```
a |= b -> a = a ou b
```

que em pascal seria

```
a := a or b;
```

(byte) é uma coerção de tipo, que significa que o resultado deve ser convertido para o tipo byte, possivelmente sendo truncado no byte menos significativo. Em pascal fazemos byte(expressão), apesar de ter outros meios que podem fazer mais sentido no contexto.

```
v ? a : b
```

Isto é o operador ternário do C, que não existe no pascal, deve ser substituído por um if :

```
If V Then
    Result := A
Else
    Result := B;
```

`<<` é o operador de deslocamento da linguagem C, que em pascal pode ser substituido por `shl`.

Ao todo, ficaria :

```
if V <> 0 then
    slice := byte(1 shl 7 - b)
else
    slice := byte(0 shl 7 - b)
```

Coloquei V <> 0 por que na prática o if (e o operador ?) do c, consideram como true qualquer coisa diferente de 0 (na verdade o C não tem tipos boleanos verdadeiros).

Comment: perfeito, resposta clara, completa e didática.